# What is the difference between in group by clause by using Index no and column no?

Tags: sql

Example 1.

```
Select a,count(b),c from table group by b;    

Select a,count(b),c from table group by 2;
```

Is there is difference in both??

Comment: Both are invalid, but in different ways.

Comment: Both queries incorrect. You should use group by from columns which not have any aggregation functions. For DBMS no difference between write column name or it index in group by clause, but for person - there are big difference to read column name, or abstract column index value from select clause

Comment: @Maxim, GROUP BY ordinal position is not valid ANSI/ISO SQL - but some products support it.